# Is it possible to write a function without return or Nil return type. Suggest an alternative

Tags: go

I have a function here that loops through and print numbers. I do not have anything to return. How can I avoid this without having to return a value?

```
func Problem1V3() Nil {
sum := 0
    for i := 3; i < 1000; i+=3 {
        fmt.Printf("i loop: %v", i)
    }
    return Nil
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
func Problem1V3() {
    for i := 3; i < 1000; i+=3 {
        fmt.Printf("i loop: %v", i)
    }
}
```

You can run it at http://play.golang.org/p/irUI1sCx_B

Comment: Thank you very much